# Less redundant code for environments

Tags: environments, thmbox

I'm using the thmbox package to create a lot of self made environments. Most of the environments simply have different names but the same code. Can someone help me getting less code, where I can change the code more easily? Here is an example of the code:

```
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M, within = section,]{Definition}%
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
    \ifblank{#1}{\begin{Definition}}{\begin{Definition}[\normalfont\bfseries #1]}%
    \normalfont%
}%
{\end{Definition}}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{definition}%

\declaretheorem[style = nonitalicstyle,thmbox=M]{Axiom}%
\newenvironment{axiom}[1][]{%
    \ifblank{#1}{\begin{Axiom}}{\begin{Axiom}[\normalfont\bfseries #1]}%
    \normalfont%
}%
{\end{Axiom}}%
\NoIndentAfterEnv{axiom}%

\declaretheorem[style = nonitalicstyle,thmbox=M]{Notation}%
\newenvironment{notation}[1][]{%
    \ifblank{#1}{\begin{Notation}}{\begin{Notation}[\normalfont\bfseries #1]}%
    \normalfont%
}%
{\end{Notation}}%
\NoIndentAfterEnv{notation}%
```

Comment: Can you please make a complete example so we don't have to guess the packages and options you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons the `titlestyle` option (`thmbox` package) does not work as expected in combination with `thmtools` and the documentations of the packages don't give much information about it.

If you want the optional argument to be printed in normal bold face you need this should be enough:

```
\setkeys{thmbox}{titlestyle=\textbf{ (#1)}}
```

which works fine with `thmbox` alone but not in combination with `thmtools`. Therefore it is also necessary

```
\usepackage[nothm]{thmbox}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage[nothm]{thmbox}
\setkeys{thmbox}{titlestyle=\textbf{ (#1)}}

\declaretheorem[style = mystyle,within=section,thmbox=M]{Definition}%
\declaretheorem[style = nonitalicstyle,thmbox=M]{Axiom}%
\declaretheorem[style = nonitalicstyle,thmbox=M]{Notation}%

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}[Euclid]
Definizione
\end{Definition}

\begin{Axiom}[Euclid]
Definizione
\end{Axiom}

\begin{Notation}[Euclid]
Definizione
\end{Notation}

\end{document}
```

[image]